# How can I split a string in Ruby based on the number of characters between it?

Tags: ruby, string, substring

I'm writing a Ruby gem at the moment but I've hit a bit of a stump as I'm trying to think of an efficient way to do below to the following:

```
P<GBRLAST<<FIRST<MIDDLE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

From that I want to get: GBR, LAST, FIRST MIDDLE as outputs

I know that I can use something like:

```
 string[2...5]
```

to output "GBR", but how would I go about getting "LAST" and "FIRST MIDDLE" as the other outputs?

There will always be `<<` between LAST and FIRST, and `<` between FIRST and MIDDLE, but LAST, FIRST and MIDDLE could be any length (they're example names) and there could be more than just FIRST and MIDDLE with the `<` separator. For example:

```
 P<GBRLAST<<FIRST<MIDDLE<LION<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

The only way I could see doing this is through progressive `if` loops, but is there a more efficient and native way to split this up I'm not seeing?

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions and captions.  If you know First is always going to have a << and last will have < your regular expression will look like something like this (not ruby):

.<(.[3])([^<]*)<<(([^<]*)<)+(.*)<<

Its a little confusing.  But the first set of parenthesis will capture the country (any three letters/numbers/etc).  the second set of parenthesis will capture the last name.  The third set will repeatedly match all the "first" names listed.  And the last set will match the middle name. I didn't test it but the regex should look pretty similar to that.

Comment: Is this a string from a passport's MRZ?

Comment: Yes it is, I've just finished a ruby gem which can parse them for you! Check it out here: https://github.com/rubyisilluminati/Verified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = "P<GBRLAST<<FIRST<MIDDLE<LION<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"

parts = a.gsub(/<+/, '<').split('<')
# => ["P", "GBRLAST", "FIRST", "MIDDLE", "LION"]
```

This collapses all '<<<<' strings into single '<' characters, then splits the string using it as a delimiter.

```
first = parts[1][0..2]
# => "GBR" 

second = parts[1][3..-1]
# => "LAST" 

the_rest = parts[2..-1]
# => ["FIRST", "MIDDLE", "LION"]
```

Do with those what you will.

This assumes 'first' will always be 3 characters long, but I can't see any other way of splitting it, unless you have more rules.

EDIT:

A few excellent optimisations suggested by commenters.

@7stud suggests:

```
parts = a.gsub(/<+/, '<').split('<')
```

can be rewritten as:

```
parts = a.split(/<+/)
```

This is also more efficient in terms of processor cycles.

```
Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { a.split(/<+/) }}
# => #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc0320b84a8 @label="", @real=0.053515, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.04999999999999999, @total=0.04999999999999999> 
Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { a.gsub(/<+/, '<').split('<') }}
# => #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc0328fe3d8 @label="", @real=0.081377, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.07999999999999996, @total=0.07999999999999996>
```

@Shadwell points out:

We can just split on a single '<' and remove the blank entries to avoid using a regex at all.

```
a.split("<").select { |s| !s.empty? }
```

Avoiding regexes is a good goal to aim for - regexes are often inefficient, being a general language applied to string manipulation rather than an optimised, targeted action. They are also opaque, error prone, edge-case prone and difficult to maintain.

In this case however, using select is a little less efficient than splitting on the regex. Also, the regex is simple enough not to worry about too much.

```
Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { a.split(/<+/) }}
# => #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc0320b84a8 @label="", @real=0.053515, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.04999999999999999, @total=0.04999999999999999>  
Benchmark.measure { 10000.times { a.split("<").select { |s| !s.empty? } }}
# => #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc032039ea0 @label="", @real=0.061219, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.06, @total=0.06>
```

It should be noted here that these speed differences wouldn't really be felt unless we were dealing with truly vast amounts of data, so code readability should come first.

@careyswoveland commented with my absolute favourite:

```
[a[2..4]].concat(a[5..-1].split(/<+/))
```

which returns a nice array of all values and copes with any number of extra strings. Takes a little mental unpacking to understand what's going on, but it's a truly beautiful example of the power and conciseness of Ruby.

Comment: This is nice and much more simple than the regex I and the other poster came up with.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this. Very clever answer, thank you.

Comment: You could also split on `"<"` and remove any blank entries: `a.split("<").select { |s| !s.empty? }` to avoid doing the `gsub`

Comment: or, a slight variant, `[a[2..4]].concat(a[5..-1].split(/<+/)) => ["GBR", "LAST", "FIRST", "MIDDLE", "LION"]`.

Comment: Both awesome solutions. :D

Comment: @CarySwoveland, actually I was hoping you'd turn up here. You didn't disappoint.

Comment: This collapses all '<<<<' strings into single '<' characters, then splits the string using it as a delimiter Which begs the question why you wouldn't just split on /<+/.

Comment: Yes indeed, good optimisation. And you can see that in use in a comment by @CarySwoveland on the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions:

```
PATTERN = /P<(GBR)([^<]*)<<((?:[^<]+<)+)<+/
def parse(str)
  match_data = PATTERN.match(str)

  gbr  = match_data[1]
  last = match_data[2]
  rest = match_data[3].split('<')

  [gbr, last, *rest]
end

puts parse('P<GBRLAST<<FIRST<MIDDLE<LION<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<').inspect
```

Prints:

```
["GBR", "LAST", "FIRST", "MIDDLE", "LION"]
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you may have to tune the Regex a bit to get what you want.

For more on regular expressions, you may find [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to be a useful site for tutorials and such. You may also find [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) to be a valuable resource for testing out and debugging any regular expressions you might write ([example](http://regex101.com/r/kD9qG5/1)).

Comment: Pretty sure you have to wrap that last capture in parenthesis before the + since there can be multiple first/middle names.

Comment: You could also write it like this: `a = str.scan(PATTERN).flatten; a[0..-2] + a[-1].split('<') #=> ["GBR", "LAST", "FIRST", "MIDDLE", "LION"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wanted to demonstrate the use of MatchData, since it's likely the OP's actual use case isn't to "return an array". But something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'P<GBRLAST<<FIRST<MIDDLE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'

puts str[2..4]

str[5..-1].scan(/[^<]+/xm) do |match|
  puts match
end

--output:--
GBR
LAST
FIRST
MIDDLE
```

It's not hard to get all the text:

```
str = 'P<GBRLAST<<FIRST<MIDDLE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'

character_groups = str.scan(/[^<]+/)
p character_groups  

--output:--
["P", "GBRLAST", "FIRST", "MIDDLE"]
```

But then there are two issues:

1)  Is the target text always the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th groups?

2)  Is GBR always exactly GBR? Or any three letter sequence?

```
puts character_groups[1][0..2]   #GBR
puts character_groups[1][3..-1]  #LAST, i.e. the rest of the string

puts character_groups[2..4]      #FIRST
                                 #MIDDLE
```